# Dynamic Reply Sender

Tags: email, send-email

I have a big doubt.. Anyone knows if it is possible to send an email from e.g geral@test.com and if someone Reply to this email this response goes to another email, like this:

1. Sent email to client@email.com from geral@email.com
2. client@email.com decides Reply the email
3. The email replied is send to otherEMail@email.com

That is possible?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Reply Mail Management is likely what you're looking for. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_reply_mail_management.htm&type=5